# ASP.NET undefined from hiddenfield value

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I'm trying to get the value from a hiddenfield but I'm getting an undefined alert. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Masterpage
...
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MasterContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($('#hiddenPersonId').val());
        });
    </script>
</body>

// Default.aspx
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenPersonId" runat="server" Value="1" />
</asp:Content>
```

I tried other solutions but these are also not working:

```
alert($("#<%= hiddenPersonId.ClientID %>").val());
```

Comment: Check the html outputted in Default.aspx, #hiddenPersonId probably is called something else and is therefore undefined when you try to find it by the id "#hiddenPersonId".

Comment: What does the *client-side* code/markup look like?

Comment: You'll get undefined if jquery can't find the element.  try this:  alert($('#hiddenPersonId').length)  - this should be 1, if 0 then your hidden field isn't in the html, if 2 or more.. well, you have more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work from master page. You need to call it from Default.aspx or try

```
 $('[id*="hiddenPersonId"]')
```

on master page but other pages that uses this master page should not have any control that contains `hiddenPersonId` in its id

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting ClientIDMode to static if you're .net 4+.  You'll want to check that it is defined first. If you want/need the js to be on master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            alert($('#hdnPersonId').val());
        });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPersonId" Value="1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: What is the reason to set `ClientIDMode="Static"`?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked in .NET, but I believe it was so that the element can be referenced by the ID specified (in client side JavaScript) - without all of the other prefixes that are applied to dom element ids by default to keep them unique.